# Is there a way to extract text after a word is stated?

Tags: python, variables, artificial-intelligence, extract, spelling

So I am trying to make a virtual assistant and am working on a spelling feature like the one on a google home.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is when I say "hey google spell cat" it will say C A T
How would I get cat into a variable?

I know how to split it

Comment: It might be helpful to provide some information on what you have tried thus far. Your question provides little information on what the current state of your application is, so it's a bit hard to assess where to point you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that you have a string and wish to store the last word in it. This can be achieved by split as you said and then assignment:

```py
text = 'hey google spell cat'
last_word = text.split()[-1]
```

If you instead want the word after spell you can just index spell and add one:

```py
text = 'hi google spell cat for me'
split = text.split()
split[split.index('spell')+1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply that is very helpful but I was wondering if there is any way to get the word after spell?

Comment: Is cat not the word after spell? This code assigns 'cat' to last_word. Do you want 'google', the word before spell?

Comment: So I know that cat is the word after spell and is the last word but is there any way to get 'cat' after the word spell so if I said "Hey Google spell cat for me" and it would still output cat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
given_text="hey google spell cat"
last_word=given_text.split()[-1]
reply=' '.join(list(last_word)).upper()

print(reply)

'C A T'
```